# How to resolve INKApi error

Tags: java, apache

We have developing the WEB product. Our one of the customer has facing `"INKApi error(500)"`error. This is something different. I have search on google. No one can solve this error.

1. What is the INKApi?
2. When this error will thrown?
3. Who will throw this error (Apache or JVM or ..?)

If anyone known how to solve this issue, kindly let us know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell this is something to do with Apache Traffic Server (ATS).  They use the prefix INK for the Traffic Server API - see http://trafficserver.apache.org/docs/v2/sdk/NamingConventions.html.  (INK appears to come from [Inktomi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inktomi) who created the codebase that became ATS.)

My guess is that the error is being generated by ATS's HttpTransact::HandleApiErrorJump method; see https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=trafficserver.git;a=blob;f=proxy/http/HttpTransact.cc

If that's the case, it is ATS that is throwing the error, and HTTP_STATUS_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR is 500.  The cause is not apparent from looking at the code.  (Get your customer to look at his ATS log files, etcetera.)

Comment: Facing the same issue. Unable to find the cause that if its the application server error or some configuration error. API calls are not reaching application server. Both links are not working

Comment: @BharatBhagat - If you can do some research to find out what the links should point to now (5 years after the question was originally answered) I will update it.   (And did you look in the logfile?)

Answer (score 1):

I got this error with incorrect request headers while calling a web service

Comment: could you mention those headers?