# Google App Engine + python 2.7: HTTP Error 500: INKApi Error

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

I am trying the very simple "Hello world program" from GAE, with one more line for logging.

```
import webapp2
import logging

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        logging.info('Executing my app.')
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write('Hello, webapp2 World!')


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage)],
                              debug=True)
```

This example runs WELL after deployment to appspot.

But with the development environment. I can see the log from Log Console, followed by INK error always. I tried to copy code from different examples, no help.

I have checked the GAE version, preference. Everything seems fine. Anyone can help?

The log:

> ```
>  INFO     2013-04-23 08:38:20,326 main.py:8] Executing my app.
>  HTTPError()
>  HTTPError()
>  Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\cherrypy\cherrypy\wsgiserver\wsgiserver2.py", line 1302, in communicate
>     req.respond()
>   File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\cherrypy\cherrypy\wsgiserver\wsgiserver2.py", line 831, in respond
>     self.server.gateway(self).respond()
>   File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\cherrypy\cherrypy\wsgiserver\wsgiserver2.py", line 2115, in respond
>     response = self.req.server.wsgi_app(self.env, self.start_response)
>   File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\wsgi_server.py", line 246, in __call__
>     return app(environ, start_response)
>   File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\request_rewriter.py", line 311, in _rewriter_middleware
>     response_body = iter(application(environ, wrapped_start_response))
>   File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\python\request_handler.py", line 89, in __call__
>     self._flush_logs(response.get('logs', []))
>   File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\python\request_handler.py", line 220, in _flush_logs
>     apiproxy_stub_map.MakeSyncCall('logservice', 'Flush', request, response)
>   File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 94, in MakeSyncCall
>     return stubmap.MakeSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
>   File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 320, in MakeSyncCall
>     rpc.CheckSuccess()
>   File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\apiproxy_rpc.py", line 156, in _WaitImpl
>     self.request, self.response)
>   File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\remote_api\remote_api_stub.py", line 200, in MakeSyncCall
>     self._MakeRealSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
>   File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\remote_api\remote_api_stub.py", line 226, in _MakeRealSyncCall
>     encoded_response = self._server.Send(self._path, encoded_request)
>   File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc.py", line 393, in Send
>     f = self.opener.open(req)
>   File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 406, in open
>     response = meth(req, response)
>   File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 519, in http_response
>     'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
>   File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 444, in error
>     return self._call_chain(*args)
>   File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
>     result = func(*args)
>   File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 527, in http_error_default
>     raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
> HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: INKApi Error
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\cherrypy\cherrypy\wsgiserver\wsgiserver2.py", line 1302, in communicate
>     req.respond()
>   File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\cherrypy\cherrypy\wsgiserver\wsgiserver2.py", line 831, in respond
>     self.server.gateway(self).respond()
>   File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\lib\cherrypy\cherrypy\wsgiserver\wsgiserver2.py", line 2115, in respond
>     response = self.req.server.wsgi_app(self.env, self.start_response)
>   File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\wsgi_server.py", line 246, in __call__
>     return app(environ, start_response)
>   File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\request_rewriter.py", line 311, in _rewriter_middleware
>     response_body = iter(application(environ, wrapped_start_response))
>   File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\python\request_handler.py", line 89, in __call__
>     self._flush_logs(response.get('logs', []))
>   File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\python\request_handler.py", line 220, in _flush_logs
>     apiproxy_stub_map.MakeSyncCall('logservice', 'Flush', request, response)
>   File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 94, in MakeSyncCall
>     return stubmap.MakeSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
>   File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 320, in MakeSyncCall
>     rpc.CheckSuccess()
>   File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\apiproxy_rpc.py", line 156, in _WaitImpl
>     self.request, self.response)
>   File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\remote_api\remote_api_stub.py", line 200, in MakeSyncCall
>     self._MakeRealSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
>   File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\remote_api\remote_api_stub.py", line 226, in _MakeRealSyncCall
>     encoded_response = self._server.Send(self._path, encoded_request)
>   File "C:\Program Files\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc.py", line 393, in Send
>     f = self.opener.open(req)
>   File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 406, in open
>     response = meth(req, response)
>   File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 519, in http_response
>     'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
>   File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 444, in error
>     return self._call_chain(*args)
>   File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
>     result = func(*args)
>   File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 527, in http_error_default
>     raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
> HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: INKApi Error
> INFO     2013-04-23 16:38:22,436 server.py:561] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 -
> ```

Comment: The string "INKApi" does not appear anywhere in the SDK code base, so this has something to do with your own environment.  I suggest you do a search for "INK" in python, and see if you have something monkeypatching urllib2 or something along those lines.

Comment: A quick search on google turns up another person on stackoverflow with the same problem   See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14210775/how-to-resolve-inkapi-error though they are using java.  Something's up with your local environment

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue INKApi error, and the answer from erickthered solved my problem : https://stackoverflow.com/a/19460147/1591720