# google app engine: Error: HTTPError

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I am trying "Hello world" with python

```
  import webapp2

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write('Hello world!')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler)
], debug=True)
```

app.yaml

```
application: engineapp
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: .*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
```

But when run in Google App Launcher get this error

```
INFO     2013-05-22 12:22:40,302 admin_server.py:117] Starting admin server at: xxxxx:8000
HTTPError()
HTTPError()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_app_engine\lib\cherrypy\cherrypy\wsgiserver\wsgiserver2.py", line 1302, in communicate
    req.respond()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_app_engine\lib\cherrypy\cherrypy\wsgiserver\wsgiserver2.py", line 831, in respond
    self.server.gateway(self).respond()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_app_engine\lib\cherrypy\cherrypy\wsgiserver\wsgiserver2.py", line 2115, in respond
    response = self.req.server.wsgi_app(self.env, self.start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_app_engine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\wsgi_server.py", line 246, in __call__
    return app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_app_engine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\request_rewriter.py", line 311, in _rewriter_middleware
    response_body = iter(application(environ, wrapped_start_response))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_app_engine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\python\request_handler.py", line 89, in __call__
    self._flush_logs(response.get('logs', []))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_app_engine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\python\request_handler.py", line 220, in _flush_logs
    apiproxy_stub_map.MakeSyncCall('logservice', 'Flush', request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_app_engine\google\appengine\api\apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 94, in MakeSyncCall
    return stubmap.MakeSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_app_engine\google\appengine\api\apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 320, in MakeSyncCall
    rpc.CheckSuccess()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_app_engine\google\appengine\api\apiproxy_rpc.py", line 156, in _WaitImpl
    self.request, self.response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_app_engine\google\appengine\ext\remote_api\remote_api_stub.py", line 200, in MakeSyncCall
    self._MakeRealSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_app_engine\google\appengine\ext\remote_api\remote_api_stub.py", line 226, in _MakeRealSyncCall
    encoded_response = self._server.Send(self._path, encoded_request)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_app_engine\google\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc.py", line 393, in Send
    f = self.opener.open(req)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 448, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable
```

I change GAE Launcher(1.7.7) version and reinstall python but does not work

I'm using Windows 7, python 2.7 and EAG Launcher 1.8.0

Comment: What is in your app.yaml file?

Comment: EDIT the question with the app.yaml

Comment: @gath, updated my app engine from 1.7.6 to 1.8 and am getting the same error on my existing projects, what is happening?

Answer (score 22):

I had this very same issue with my MacOSX when using a proxy server using Google App Engine Launcher 1.8.6 behind a proxy server.  Apparently there's an issue with "proxy_bypass" on "urllib2.py".

There are two possible solutions:

1. Downgrade to 1.7.5, but, who wants to downgrade?
2. Edit "[GAE Instalattion path]/google/appengine/tools/appengine_rpc.py" and look for the line that says

   `opener.add_handler(fancy_urllib.FancyProxyHandler())`

In my computer it was line 578, and then put a hash (#) at the beginning of the line, like this:

```
`#opener.add_handler(fancy_urllib.FancyProxyHandler())`
```

Save the file, stop and then restart your application.  Now dev_appserver.py shouldn't try to use any proxy server at all.

If your application uses any external resources like a SOAP Webservice or something like that and you can't reach the server without the proxy server, then you'll have to downgrade.  Please keep in mind that external javascript files (like facebook SDK or similar) are loaded from your browser, not from your application.

Since I'm not using any external REST or SOAP services it worked for me!

Hopefully it will work for you as well.

Comment: This did not work in linux, resulting in `fancy_urllib.InvalidCertificateException: Host appengine.google.com returned an invalid certificate (_ssl.c:510: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed): 
`

Comment: Genious! Now i can develop behind my corporate proxy

Comment: Great, it works for windows too!, you can find the file in: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc.py.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is to remove all of the proxy settings via:

    `unset http_proxy https_proxy ftp_proxy ftps_proxy`

Then restart the app via 

`dev_appserver.py helloworld/`

If you are under windows, then you have to change the "Internet Options" of IE Configuration.

Answer (score -2):

You might want to try running your app from the command line. Run

```
dev_appserver.py --port=8080 myapp
```

from your app's directory and replace "myapp" with the name of your application.

More info can be found in the GAE docs:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver#Running_the_Development_Web_Server