# GAE 1.9.27 not working on windows x64

Tags: python, windows, google-app-engine

Same code working on Linux x64, but fail both win7 and win10.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\cherrypy\cherrypy\wsgiserver\wsgiserver2.py", line 1302, in communicate
    req.respond()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\cherrypy\cherrypy\wsgiserver\wsgiserver2.py", line 831, in respond

    self.server.gateway(self).respond()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\cherrypy\cherrypy\wsgiserver\wsgiserver2.py", line 2115, in respond
    response = self.req.server.wsgi_app(self.env, self.start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\wsgi_server.py", line 272, in __call__
    return app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\request_rewriter.py", line 314, in     _rewriter_middleware
    response_body = iter(application(environ, wrapped_start_response))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\python\request_handler.py", line 159,     in __call__
    self._flush_logs(response.get('logs', []))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\python\request_handler.py", line 278,     in _flush_logs
    apiproxy_stub_map.MakeSyncCall('logservice', 'Flush', request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 95, in MakeSyncCall
    return stubmap.MakeSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 329, in MakeSyncCall
    rpc.CheckSuccess()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\apiproxy_rpc.py", line 157, in _WaitImpl
    self.request, self.response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\remote_api\remote_api_stub.py", line 201, in     MakeSyncCall
    self._MakeRealSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\remote_api\remote_api_stub.py", line 227, in     _MakeRealSyncCall
    encoded_response = self._server.Send(self._path, encoded_request)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc.py", line 393, in Send
    f = self.opener.open(req)
  File "c:\Python27\Lib\urllib2.py", line 437, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "c:\Python27\Lib\urllib2.py", line 550, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "c:\Python27\Lib\urllib2.py", line 475, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "c:\Python27\Lib\urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "c:\Python27\Lib\urllib2.py", line 558, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
HTTPError: HTTP Error 502: Server dropped connection
```

Python version:

```
(venv) C:\Users\jejer\Desktop\zhipda>python
Python 2.7.10 (default, May 23 2015, 09:44:00) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

start script:

```
(venv) C:\Users\jejer\Desktop\zhipda>python "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\dev_appserver.py" .
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have any systemwide proxy configured? If yes try to disable it.
It does look similar to this issue [google app engine: Error: HTTPError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16698621/google-app-engine-error-httperror)