# Google app engine endpoints api not working in localhost

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am trying to start a python app-engine project on localhost. I am in a Windows 8.1 machine (Python version 2.7). The project code is copied from here [link](https://github.com/udacity/ud858/tree/master/Lesson_2/000_Hello_Endpoints). The server seems to start but the page wouldn't properly load due to some problem. Probably it can't reach the api server.

Here is a shot from firebug showing the failed request

[image]

What seems off to me is that in command prompt (I started the dev server from there) the API server is started at some random port other than the module port. But the webpage is trying to access the `http://127.0.0.1:8000/_ah/api/static/proxy.html...` page at the module port. I tried accessing it at the API server port it does open some page there. (I mean I tried opening `http://127.0.0.1:1532/_ah/api/static/proxy.html...` seperately) It returns some json I don't understand...

```
{app_id: dev~udatut-bs, rtok: '0'}
```

Command prompt log:

[image]

Here's the difference between the outputs in localhost and *.appspot.com

**Should get this:**
[image]

**But stuck here:(check buttons are not loaded)**
[image]

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: The page is not loading fully and no ajax request to the endpoint api is getting through...

Comment: which version of the sdk are you using ?

Comment: sdk for Windows version 1.9.28 - 2015-10-29

Comment: what do you see at you API explorer  http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/explorer ?

Comment: it says webpage could not be loaded!!!

Comment: @Bishal, MayK mistyped the explorer URL, it should be http://127.0.0.1:8000/_ah/api/explorer based on your command line flags. Does that one give the same error? What is the error shown in firebug along with the RED error URL?

Comment: @JoshTriiJohnston the url redirects me to https://apis-explorer.appspot.com/apis-explorer/#p/ and the error for the red url is status `Aborted`

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/QaDQl.png

Comment: Is there an error in your app engine dev_appserver.py console when the static/proxy.html url is requested? I ran the application from github and their aren't any errors.

Comment: @JoshTriiJohnston no I couldn't find any error logged in the console for that particular request...

Answer (score 0):

**I finally found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19460147/2713198).**

Steps for windows:

1. Goto your google appengine installation folder and then ./google/appengine/toots. (C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools) if you followed default installation instructions.
2. Open the file **appengine_rpc.py** and look for the line (towards the end of the file)

   ```
   opener.add_handler(fancy_urllib.FancyProxyHandler())
   ```

   and comment it out like

   ```
   # opener.add_handler(fancy_urllib.FancyProxyHandler())
   ```
3. Close the app and restart it again.